# Problema metodo GET php al leer un archivo txt xxx.php?txt=archivo.txt?

Tags: php

Hola hago esta pregunta ya que estoy un poco atorado con GEt php saben de quiero leer no descargar un txt,  ya sea con url externna soy nuevo en php aun batallo poco en entender. Quiero crear urls así **xxx.php?link=http://xxx** method get o así **xxx.php?txt=archivo.txt** . Lo que pasa que este código solo descarga no lo lee; "es lo quiero que me leea el archivo que le indique", quiero saber en que estoy mal :( gracias   mi codigo es

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['file']) || empty($_GET['txt'])) {
  exit();
}
$root = "txt/";
$file = basename($_GET['file']);
$path = $root.$file;
$type = '';

if (is_file($path)) {
  $size = filesize($path);

  if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
    $type = mime_content_type($path);
  }
  else if (function_exists('finfo_file')) {
    $info = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $type = finfo_file($info, $path);
    finfo_close($info);
  }

  if ($type == '') {
    $type = "application/force-download";
  }

  // Definir headers
  header("Content-Type: $type");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header("Content-Length: " . $size);

  // Descargar archivo
  readfile($path);
}
else {
  die("El archivo txt no existe.");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día, para leer un archivo desde php se utiliza la funcion [fgets()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php)

```
<?php
$gestor = @fopen("/tmp/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($gestor) {
    while (($búfer = fgets($gestor, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $búfer;
    }
    if (!feof($gestor)) {
        echo "Error: fallo inesperado de fgets()\n";
    }
    fclose($gestor);
}
?>
```

Comment: me sirvió código me funciono como quería muchas gracias. Aquí esta la prueba   `<?php
 
$file = $_GET['file'];
  // leer archivo
$gestor = @fopen($file, "r");
header("Content-disposition: filename=$file");
if ($gestor) {
    while (($búfer = fgets($gestor, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $búfer;
    }
    if (!feof($gestor)) {
        echo "Error: fallo inesperado de fgets()\n";
    }
    fclose($gestor);
}

?>` [enlace] https://m-go.ga/link/dc.php?list=https://pastebin.com/raw/3596T0M0[/enlace]